# store part of outcome command to variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Hello dear people and others,

Today i wanted to create a simple script, thought it would be easy to store the outcome to var of the following command:

```
wmic bios get serialnumber | findstr /N /V SerialNumber
```

Outcome:

```
2:H3GK4S1
3:
```

The problem is when i try to get the serial with wmic, it returns the string as expected but also an empty string/line. When i try to store the serial to a variable it stores it and then directly overwrites it with the empty string. This is the function i nearly got working now:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %g IN ('Wmic Bios Get SerialNumber ^| FINDSTR /N /V SerialNumber') DO (SET serial=%g & ECHO %g)
```

And this gives the following output:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %g IN ('Wmic Bios Get SerialNumber ^| FINDSTR /N /V SerialNumber') DO (SET serial=%g & ECHO %g)
2:H3GK4S1
3:
```

As can be seen above, the loop overwrites the serial var, if someone can help me towards the right directon to get this working, would be mad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the Command Prompt:

```bat
For /F "Tokens=1* Delims==" %g In ('WMIC BIOS Get SerialNumber /Value') Do @For /F "Tokens=*" %i In ("%h") Do @Set "serial=%i" & Echo %i
```

Or in a batch file:

```bat
@For /F "Tokens=1* Delims==" %%g In ('WMIC BIOS Get SerialNumber /Value'
) Do @For /F "Tokens=*" %%i In ("%%h") Do @Set "serial=%%i" & Echo %%i
@Pause
```

**Edit**
If you're happy to use a labelled section in your batch file:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "serial="
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In ('WMIC BIOS Get SerialNumber') Do If Not Defined serial Call :Sub %%A
Set serial 2>Nul
Pause
GoTo :EOF

:Sub
Set "serial=%*"
GoTo :EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like [**this**](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4266):

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %g IN ('Wmic Bios Get SerialNumber /format:value') DO for /f "tokens=* delims=" %# in ("%g") do set "serial=%#"

echo %serial%
```

Mind that's a command that should be executed in the command prompt directly.For a batch file you'll need to double the `%` in the for loop tokens.

Answer (score 1):

In a batch file, you can also use a `goto` to end the loop after the first iteration :

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('wmic bios get serialnumber ^| findstr /N /V SerialNumber') do (
  set "$var=%%a"
  goto:next
)

exit/b

:next
echo Result=^> [%$var: =%]
```